# Understanding the proof for subaddtivity of outer measure

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $A_1, A_2, \dots \subset \Bbb R^n$. Show that $$m^*\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \right) \leqslant \sum_{i=1}^\infty m^*(A_i).$$

I'm trying to understand the proof for this, but have a bit trouble understanding the part highlighted.

Let $\varepsilon >0$ and define Lebesgue covers for $A_j$ as follows. $\mathcal{F_j} = \{I_{j1}, I_{j2}, \dots\}$. Now from the definition of outer measure we have that $$m^*(A_j)= \inf\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty \ell(I_i) \mid A_j \subset \cup_{i=1}^\infty I_i \}$$

thus $$\color{red}{\sum_{i=1}^\infty \ell(I_{j,i}) \leqslant m^*(A_j) + \frac{\varepsilon}{2^j}}.$$

Now denote $\mathcal{F} = \cup_j \mathcal{F_j} = \{I_{j,k} \mid j,k \in \Bbb N\}$ which is a cover for $A=\cup_jA_j$ and we have that $$\color{red}{\begin{align} \quad m^* \left ( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \right ) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left ( \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \ell(I_{n, m}) \right )\end{align}} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left ( m^*(A_n) + \frac{\epsilon}{2^n} \right ) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} m^*(A_n) + \epsilon \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \to \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} m^*(A_n).$$

How are is the first one true? Isn't $m^*(A_j)$ defined to be the infima of the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ell(I_{n})$ then how can it ever be greater than the sum even if you add the term $\frac{\varepsilon}{2^j}$ that will just get arbitarily small?

Similarly the second highlighted part. That one seems correct to me but wouldn't it contradict the first one?

Comment: If $c=\inf A$ the $c \leq a$ for all $a \in A$. Also, $c+\epsilon$ cannot be a lower bound for $A$ so it must exceed some element of $A$.

Comment: the inequality $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \ell(I_{j,i}) \leqslant m^*(A_j) + \frac{\varepsilon}{2^j}$ is false in general for arbitrary $I_{j,i}$, however there exists infinitely many $I_{j,i}$ for what its true